# Sending forgot password of user in an email works successfully in local machine but fails on server using c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am developing a small application in asp.net using C#, where if user forgets password, I want to send the password from database to user's mail when clicked on forget password button. I was successful in sending the password in an email but in local machine. The settings which I am using, on the local machine, I used on the server too. But if I try on the server, I was thrown with an error saying "Failure sending email". Can anybody please tell me where I am making a mistake and what to do further if it has to work in server.

Below is my code :

```
try
        {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                 {
                    MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();

                    Msg.From = new MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com");

                    Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtboxforgotemail.Text));
                    Msg.Subject = "Forgot Password :";
                    Msg.Body = "Hi, Dear '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["username"] + "' , your password is:" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["password"] + "";
                    Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtp.Port = 587;
                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential ("mymail@gmail.com","mypassword");
                    smtp.Send(Msg);
                    lblforgotemail.Text = "Your Password Details Sent to your mail";
                    txtboxforgotemail.Text = "";
             }
             else
                    {
                        lblforgotemail.Text = "The email you entered does not exist.";
                    }  
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtboxforgotemail.Text = "";
            lblforgotemail.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

Comment: whats the exception? did you debug the application?

Comment: Try determine exactly exseption instead catch general and get only message

Comment: 1) You're storing plaintext passwords? Seriously? Read [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) 2) You're enabling html but you don't apply entity encoding to the dynamic fields (e.g. username). At minimum that's a bug, but in many contexts it's even a security hole.

Comment: Perhaps this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686383/failure-sending-mail-in-asp-net-mvc4-smtp-sendmail) will help

Comment: Does your firewall allow traffic on port 587?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the exact same thing working in a live environment, the only difference is I have the following properties set on my smtp class as well:

```
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue few days back.
Remove smtp.Port = 587 from your code and it will work

Comment: Hi Manu, I could not get the correct result after removing smtp.Port=587.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try
        {
            string admin_email = "youremail"
            string admin_emailpwd = "your pwd"

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(SendTo);
            mail.From = new MailAddress(admin_email);
            mail.Subject = Subject;
            mail.Body = Body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "SMTP.gmail.com";
          //  smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(admin_email, admin_emailpwd);
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This is my code and it works too. (NOTE: I've commented smtp.port)